# What's the correct way to do tambora on guitar?

Tags: guitar, technique

In Francisco Tarrega's *Gran Jota*, there's tambora where you hit the bridge with your thumb.

I've seen people play tambora just with one string instead off all string (as played on *Gran Jota*)

Do both way doing tambora's right? Or is there any other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From Wikipedia:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tambour_%28guitar_technique%29)

> Variation in tone can be achieved by striking different distances from the bridge and using different parts of the thumb (especially fleshy vs. bony parts).
>
> Variation in chord texture can be achieved by selecting different strings to strike.

Seems like if you're asking if it is correct to either hit all of the strings or only one, the answer is **yes**, it's fine. I imagine it would be more difficult to hit all the strings at once, but that's where you experiment with other parts of your hand instead of your thumb.